# mypy plugin callback not being called

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to make my first mypy plugin to add typechecking for this code

`adt.py`

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

def adt(datatype, *ctrs: str):
    basecls = type(datatype, (), {})
    klass = lambda x: x.split()[0]
    fields = lambda x: x.split()[1:]
    clss = (make_dataclass(klass(cls),
                           bases=(basecls,),
                           fields=fields(cls))
            for cls in ctrs)
    return (basecls, *clss)


Maybe, Just, None_ = adt("Maybe", "Just x", "None")

j = Just(1)


def foo(m: Maybe):
    pass
```

I create a `adt_plugin.py` file saved to disk and configured `mypy.ini` to load it, it's being loaded (I can see some of the prints), but it seems that my plugin callback is not being called, what I'm missing?

My plugin code doesn't do nothing, it just fails by now

`adt_plugin.py`

```
from typing import *
from mypy.plugin import Plugin, DynamicClassDefContext

T = TypeVar('T')
CB = Optional[Callable[[T], None]]


class AdtPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_dynamic_class_hook(self, fullname: str) -> 'CB[DynamicClassDefContext]':
        print(fullname)
        if fullname == "adt.adt":
            print("foo")
            print(decl_info_hook)
            return decl_info_hook
        return None


def plugin(version: str):
    # ignore version argument if the plugin works with all mypy versions.
    return AdtPlugin

def decl_info_hook(ctx : DynamicClassDefContext) -> None:
    ctx.api.fail("Not able to calculate MRO for declarative base", ctx.call)
```

`mypy.ini` (on the current folder)

```
[mypy]
plugins = /home/geckos/code/python/adt_plugin.py
```

When I run `mypy adt.py` I see:

```
 python mypy --no-incremental adt.py
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
builtins.object
adt.adt
foo
<function decl_info_hook at 0x7f55cabf9ab0>
adt.Just
builtins.type
adt.py:19: error: Variable "adt.Maybe" is not valid as a type
adt.py:19: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So there is `foo`, so that `AdtPlugin.get_dynamic_class_hook` is being called, and it's returning the `decl_info_hook` too, the function name is right, we can see it in the print, but the function is not called at all, I put an error on it, I also tried `raise Exception("foooo")` inside of it but nothings happens.

Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the problem, mypy won't detect this `x, y, ..., z = something()` as a dynamic class creation. The statement need to have the form `a = f()` where a single value is assigned, otherwise it won't call the plugin hook.